# C++ How to calculate area of square,rect, and cross. User will input the co-ordinates

Tags: c++, math

As mention on my title, how do i calcuate the area of square ,rect and cross?
The user will input all the coordinates. For square and rect , the area is easy but cross, how do i do it? And if user criss-cross input the coordinates, how do i get the length and width for all the three so that my area calculation is accurate??
Below is the illustration of a cross, which is quite tricky..

```
    ****
    *  *
 ****  ****
 *        *
 ****  ****
    *  *
    ****

//this is for square and rectangle,but to take note,user will input from from bottom left to right, then top right to left, so the caculation below will than work
l = (((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2))^(1/2);
w = (((x1-x4)^2 + (y1-y4)^2))^(1/2);
A=l*w;
```

And how do i get the coordinate points on the shapes and coordinate points in shape ?

Example: Coordinates for square is (1,1),(3,1),(1,3),(3,3)

so coordinate in square is (2,2)

and coordinate on square is (1,2),(2,1),(3,2),(2,3)

Comment: cross consists of 5 rectangles, so the calculation should be easy

Comment: The area of the cross can be calculated as follows: Area(horizontal bar) + Area(vertical bar) - Area(intersection between the horizontal bar and the vertical bar). Thus you only need 4 coordinates. The area of the intersection is (width of vertical bar * height of horizontal bar).

Comment: By "coordinate in square" and "coordinate on square" do you mean "the centre of the square" and "a point on the edge of the square"?

Comment: @Rook yes , "coordinate in square" is the center of the square, and "coordinate on square" is points on the lines which makes up the square, excluding the user input coordinates

Comment: Is the cross shape computed from just 4 coordinates, or will the user input the coordinates of each corner point (of which there are 8), or something else?

Comment: @Rook user will input 12 coordinates

Comment: All 12? Either there's a lot of redundancy in there and you're still enforcing a simple cross shape, or you're allowing users to specigy cross-shapes with no right-angles in them. Seems like your spec is a little short on detail.

Answer (score 3):

The cross is the superposition of two rectangles, but you have to countthe overlapping area only once.

The total area is:

the area of:

```
 ****
 *  *
 *  *
 *  *
 *  *
 *  *
 ****
```

plus the area of

```
 **********
 *        *
 **********
```

minus the area of:

```
 ****
 *  *
 ****
```

Get the **absolute value** of the result to avoid problems with coordinates being in the wrong order - areas are always positive.

Answer (score 0):

```
      a
     |--|
   c ****
  |--*  *
 -****  ****
b|*        *
 -****  ****
     *  *
     ****

 A = (a+b) * (2c+a) - a*b
```

So, you really only need to identify 4 coordinates. Top left and top right of the vertical bar, and the top left and bottom left coordinates of the horizontal bar.

Top left vertical: `y_tlv=y_max, x_tlv = {x_min where y=y_max}`
Top right vertical: `y_trv=y_max, x_trv = {x_max where y=y_max}`
Top left horizontal: `y_tlh={y_max where x=x_min}, x_tlh=x_min`
Bottom left horizontal: `y_blh={y_min where x=x_min}, x_blh=x_min`

```
a = abs(x_trv - x_tlv)
b = abs(y_tlh - y_blh)
c = abs(x_tlv - x_tlh)
```

I'll leave to you to figure out the algorithm to identify the required coordinate points.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the user will be required to input at the very least the following 4 co-ordinates:

```
       C1 * * *
       *      *
       *      *
C2 * * *      * * * *
*                   *
*                   *
*  * * *      * * * C3
       *      *
       *      *
       * * * C4
```

Now from the same you can calculate the co-ordinates of 3 rectangles:

```
       *  * * *
       *  1   *
       *      *
*  * * * **** * * * *
*         2         *
*                   *
*  * * * **** * * * *
       *  3   *
       *      *
       * * *  *
```

and eventually the area of the cross.

Answer (score 0):

Given a simple-ish cross shape like this:

```
    A---B
    |   |
 C--D   E--------F
 |    X  Y       |
 G--H   I--------J
    |   |
    K---L
```

You can, as pointed out above, find the areas of the three quadrilaterals and calculate the area of the whole figure... ABLK + CFJG - DEHI. This works even for skewed crosses which don't have right-angles.

How you compute the centroid of the cross depends on what you actually want, either X or Y. To get Y you must first find the bounding quadrilateral of the cross, and then it will be simple to find the centroid of that quadrilateral. Remember that if you allow unequal arm lengths like I've drawn above, point Y need not be contained within the cross itself!

To find centroid X, you'll need to work out the midpoints of AB and KL, and the midpoints of CG and FJ. You can then find the point of intersection of those two lines, AB-KL and CG-FJ to find the crossing point X which will be inside the cross, so long as the cross has a regular shape.

If you allow an arbitrary cross shape (so, for example, there might be no right angles in the cross at all) I don't think you can guarantee that point X will lie within the shape either, but I'm too lazy to prove this one way or another.

To find an arbitrary point on the perimeter of the shape is easy enough; you just need to pick any pair of corners linked by an edge (say, EF or KH) and pick a point on the vector between the two